# IndexOutOfBoundsException for automation

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to automate an application. For that, i am using hash map for excel data set and i have created my methods for performing action on that data.

Class file to execute is shown below

```
@Test
    public void testLAP_Creamix() throws Exception {
        try {
            launchMainApplication();

            Lapeyre_frMain Lapeyre_frMainPage = new Lapeyre_frMain(tool, test, user, application);

            HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> win = CreamixWindowsDataset.main();
            SortedSet<String> keys = new TreeSet<>(win.keySet());

            for (String i : keys) {
                System.out.println("########### Test = " + win.get(i).get(0) + " ###########");
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.EnterTaille(win.get(i).get(1));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.SelectCONFIGURATION(win.get(i).get(2));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.SelectPLANVASQUE(win.get(i).get(3));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.SelectCOULEUR(win.get(i).get(4));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.SelectPOIGNEES(win.get(i).get(5));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.SelectTYPE_DE_MEUBLE(win.get(i).get(6));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyPanierPrice(win.get(i).get(7));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyECO_PARTPrice(win.get(i).get(8));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.ClickCREAMIXReinit();
                System.out.println("########### Test End ##############");
            }

            test.setResult("pass");
        } catch (AlreadyRunException e) {
        } catch (Exception e) {
            verificationErrors.append(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }

    }
```

Hash Map code :

```
public static HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> main() throws IOException {

        final String DatasetSheet = "src/test/resources/CreamixDataSet.xlsx";
        final String DatasetTab = "Creamix";

        Object[][] ab = DataLoader.ReadMyExcelData(DatasetSheet, DatasetTab);

        int rowcount = DataLoader.myrowCount(DatasetSheet, DatasetTab);
        int colcount = DataLoader.mycolCount(DatasetSheet, DatasetTab);

        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

        // i = 2 to avoid column names
        for (int i = 2; i < rowcount;) {
            ArrayList<String> mycolvalueslist = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int j = 0; j < colcount;) {
                mycolvalueslist.add(ab[i][j].toString());
                j++;
            }
            map.put(ab[i][0].toString(), mycolvalueslist);
            i++;
        }

        return map;
    }
```

Query: I was able to run this code few days back, but now after adding some new columns it is giving me below mentioned error.
IndexOutOfBoundsException Index 7 out of bounds for length 7

I am not able to trace the issue here, what should i look for? please help!

Comment: please add the entire stacktrace

Comment: well, I suspect that your `colcount` is only 7, but you try to access `win.get(i).get(7)` and `win.get(i).get(8)`.

Comment: Side note: it is extremely unidiomatic to place the increment statements inside the body - why not leave them in the place inside the `for(init;condition;increment)` where they belong?

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (String i : keys) {
            arr = win.get(i);//debug here,watch it size
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.EnterTaille(arr.get(1));
            
            
        }
```